# Javascript - Bind Class Methods to Proxy Object

Tags: javascript

I am using the Javascript Proxy system to allow individual functions to subscribe to any changes in an object defined by a class. For example purposes, say this is my code:

```js
class Data {
    i = 0;
    increment() {
        this.i++;
    }
}

const obj = new Data();
const objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, prop) {
        return Reflect.get(target, prop, objProxy);
    },
    set: function(target, prop, value) {
        console.log("setting", prop, "of", target);
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, value, objProxy);
    }
});

objProxy.increment();
console.log(objProxy.i);
```

The issue is that the `this` reference in the `increment` function is a reference to the object itself, not the proxy, so the proxy setter doesn't seem to be triggered.

I tried to specify the object proxy as the "receiver" option for both the getter and the setter, expecting that the "this" reference would be changed to the proxy and the log message would be triggered when "i" is changed.

Comment: "*The issue is that the `this` reference in the `increment` function is a reference to the object itself, not the proxy*" - no it isn't? I fixed some syntax errors (missing comma, missing parens) in your code and it runs just like it should, see the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does trigger with your snippet. Make sure there are no syntax errors as I added some missing commas and brackets.

```js
class Data {
    i = 0
    increment() {
        this.i++;
    }
}

const obj = new Data();
const objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: function(target, prop) {
        return Reflect.get(target, prop, objProxy);
    },
    set: function(target, prop, value) {
        console.log("setting", prop, "of", target);
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, value, objProxy);
    }
});

objProxy.increment();
console.log(objProxy.i, obj.i);
```

Comment: It seems that the error must be somewhere else in my implementation. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need the `get` trap since it does nothing
2. You can use `Reflect.set(...arguments);` in a trap to shorten code
3. You can return the proxy from the constructor so all all objects are trackable automatically

```js
class Data {
    constructor(){
      return new Proxy(this, {
          set: function(target, prop, value) {
              console.log("setting", prop, "of", target);
              return Reflect.set(...arguments);
          }
      });
    }
    i = 0
    increment() {
        this.i++;
    }
}

const obj = new Data();

obj.increment();
console.log(obj.i, obj.i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a working code! Just some syntax mistakes.

1.On the ninth line `const objProxy = new Proxy(obj {`  missed "**,**" after **obj**
should have been `const objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {`

2. On the seventeenth line `);`  missed "**}**" before "**)**"
   should have been `});`

Great code, inform me if I helped you please)